# how to use filter function of MongoDB in Pycharm?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, filter, pycharm

I am a new guy for DB operation. 
When I use MongoDB in Pycharm, it's hard for me [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRf59.png)to manual find data. 
But I find some fields like 'filter','sort','Projection',so how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

In the Filter field you can enter (without "): "{field: 'value'}"

So for instance if you have a collection 'transactions' with the following documents:

```
{ "_id"  : <some unique id>,
  "type" : <'TE' or 'MT' or 'SE'>,
  "value": <some value>
}
```

You can find all document with type 'TE' bij entering "{type: 'TE}" in the Filter field.

For an explenation of the Project Field see: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/